How to get access token in Azure
I'm trying to fetch the secrets from the Azure key vault from .Net console application using REST API. Below is the code I'm trying to use for this from net.
Below way I'm trying to get access token and secret value:
 using Newtonsoft.Json;
 using System;
  using System.Net.Http;
  using System.Net.Http.Headers;
  using System.Text;
 using System.Text.Json;

 namespace KeyVaultSecretFetcher
 {
 class Program
 {
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Replace with your Key Vault URL, secret name, and authentication token
        string keyVaultUrl = "https://KeyVault.vault.azure.net";
        string secretName = "Test3";
        //string accessToken = "<your-access-token>";
        string tenantId = "tenantId";  // Your tenant ID
        string clientId = "clientId";  // Your application (client) ID
        string clientSecret = "clientSecret Vaule ";  // Your client secret
        
       
        string accessToken = await GetAccessToken(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        string
 secretUrl = $"{keyVaultUrl}/secrets/{secretName}?api-version=7.3";

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(secretUrl);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var secret = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Secret>(responseBody);
            Console.WriteLine("Secret value: " + secret.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error fetching secret: " + response.StatusCode);
        }
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var body = new StringContent($"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={clientId}&client_secret={clientSecret}&resource=https://vault.azure.net", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            var response = await client.PostAsync($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token", body);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            dynamic tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse);
            return tokenResponse.access_token;
        }
    }

    class Secret
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
  }
 }

However, I'm unable to fetch the secret value. Is there anything wrong in the code or settings?

Notes
This is how API permission is given:

and, app permission is disabled somehow (not sure why). So I have given delegated permission as below:

How to get the secret value? I need to achieve this via REST API only.

the app you're using need permission at the key vault level via access policy or RBAC. Also any reaon why not using the SDK? Any reason not using managed identity ?

it is quite trivial using key vault reference for app service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli

Could you check and confirm what access key vault is configured with? Vault access policy or Azure RBAC?

There is a obfuscation here, API permission of Azure Key Vault is not needed here which be a delegated type permission, but you are following the app role permission here, so the delegate permission will not take effects.  What you only needed is to add Key Vault Secrets Officer role assignment to your Service principal via resource Access Control (IAM) 

@Thomas - As applications is using .Net framework 4.5 and 4. The main reason is Visual Studio not allowing me to add the required SDK and "Key vault and Entra ID related namespace". However, if you have any idea how to use the AKV SDK with .Net framework 4.5 and 4 - Please suggest . Thanks

I have one key vault named srikv2810 with access configured as Azure RBAC as below:

Now I created one secret named secret01 in above key vault with value as:

To get this secret value via REST API with token generated using service principal, make sure to add "Key Vault Secrets User" role to application under key vault.
Initially, I registered one application and granted same API permissions as below:

Now, I added "Key Vault Secrets User" role to above app registration under key vault like this:

When I ran your code in my environment to get secret value, I too got blank results:

To resolve this, make use of below modified code where I got secret content successfully in response:
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace KeyVaultSecretFetcher
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string keyVaultUrl = "https://kvname.vault.azure.net";
            string secretName = "secret1";
            string tenantId = "tenantId";
            string clientId = "appId";
            string clientSecret = "secret";

            string accessToken = await GetAccessToken(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            string secretUrl = $"{keyVaultUrl}/secrets/{secretName}?api-version=7.3";

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(secretUrl);

            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                try
                {
                    var secret = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Secret>(responseBody);
                    Console.WriteLine("Secret value: " + secret?.Value);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error deserializing secret value: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error fetching secret: {response.StatusCode}");
            }
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var body = new StringContent($"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={clientId}&client_secret={clientSecret}&resource=https://vault.azure.net", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                var response = await client.PostAsync($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token", body);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                dynamic tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse);
                return tokenResponse.access_token;
            }
        }

        class Secret
        {
            [JsonPropertyName("value")]
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }
    }
}

Response:

